# view and print a pdf file in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, printing

My question is very very easy i just need a trick to solve it

I have 5 pdf files such as file1.pdf, file2.pdf, file3.pdf, file4.pdf and file5.pdf in my project folder. I am displaying these pdf files in 5 rows and in each row i have given two buttons that is VIEW, PRINT in index.jsp.

If VIEW button will be clicked then i want to see the corresponing pdf file and if PRINT button will be clicked then corresponding pdf file will be sent to print screen. I have lots of pdf files so in stead of wrting these pdf file names in index.jsp, i have created one table pdf_file and having one column pdf_file_name.

How can i view and print a respective pdf file when that button(view or print) will be clicked in that row?

```
 <%
  ps=('select distinct pdf_file_name from pdf_file');

 //ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
  .............

  %>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>
  PDF FILE NAMES click on a respective pdf file to view or print
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>
  <a href='<%=pdf_file_name%>'><%=pdf_file_name%></a>  
  <input type="button" value="View">// button to view that respective pdf file

  <input type="button" value="Print">// button to print that respective pdf file
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Useful question, so +1. But what you have tried.

Comment: i was trying with `window.print(); by onclick event` in button but that index.jsp is coming in print screen but i want that `file1.pdf` to come to print screen

Comment: refer to this link, you may get some help to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687675/can-a-pdf-files-print-dialog-be-opened-with-javascript

Comment: ya it helped me little bit but my question slightly differs so is there any solution for my question? how can i view/print pdf files by button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to print a PDF directly with a link/button using pure HTML/Javascript, *without an external window or iframe*. This is because of the way files/storage/security/dialog handling is implemented from browsers to browsers and server side. **For the most part, no matter how you code it in, a user WILL get a print dialog or open window with the PDF for confirmation before printing**

Some options you may want to look into

- iframes or Jquery/Ajax to load the PDF in another frame/window and an event to print when its opened. Check this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628757/save-as-pdf-recommend-a-server-solution-to-receive-raw-data-from-client-and-sen) to see how it could possible be done
- Server side language such as PHP or Python to handle the PDF conversion/printing. (Php has [DomPDF](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/), [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) and other libraries.
- Show a DIV near the the Open `a href` explaining to your users how to Right click->Save as and then print it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. In order for the file to print without the client downloading it, the browser would need to be able to display the file (which most browsers can't). This isn't much different from being unable to print a pdf from windows, if you don't have a pdf reader installed.

If you can display the pdf inline on a page (converted to an image, or something like that), you could point a hidden iframe to a page containing the pdf, and print the contents of the iframe. That would at least give the impression of printing the file without opening it first.